# Qt: как проверить query.value на нуль

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть объект класса QSqlQuery query.
В query попадает результат некоторого запроса. 
Как проверить то что хранится в query.value на NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `value` класса `QSqlQuery` возвращает значение типа `QVariant`. Следовательно, для проверки на `null` вам необходимо использовать методы класса `QVariant`. [QVariant::isNull](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#isNull). Пример использования:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT country FROM artist");
while (query.next()) {
    if (query.value(0).isNull)
        qDebug() << "Null";
}
```